# i have a flat arrays that have parent ids and i want to make it nested and like a tree parent child array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, parent-child

hi friends i have a flat array in react and it has parent field and i want make  a simple javacsript algorithm or a react algorithm with mapping and  that  make it nested and like a tree relational array

```
this.state = {
    Catgeory: [
        {id:'1' , name:'parent_1' , parentId:'0'},
        {id:'2' , name:'child_1' , parentId:'1'},
        {id:'3' , name:'child_2' , parentId:'1'},

        {id:'4' , name:'parent_2' , parentId:'0'},
        {id:'5' , name:'child_1' , parentId:'4'},
        {id:'6' , name:'child_2' , parentId:'4'},
    ],
}
```

**i want this array to be like this** and then if it happens  i can map into the array  with my way ...

```
Catgeory: [
    {
        id:'1' ,
        name:'parent_1' ,
        parentId:'0',
        subCategory: [{
            id:'2' ,
            name:'child_1',
            parentId:'1'
        }, {
            id:'3' ,
            name:'child_2' ,
            parentId:'1'
        }]
    }, {
        id:'4' ,
        name:'parent_2' ,
        parentId:'0',
        subCategory: [{
            id:'5' ,
            name:'child_1',
            parentId:'4'
        }, {
            id:'6' ,
            name:'child_2' ,
            parentId:'4'
        }]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you would loop through the array and find anything with `parentId === 0`, make a new array with those elements and add a 'subcategory' array to each one.

Then you'd loop through, find where `parentId !== 0`, match up the parent to the new element, and push the new element into the parents `subcategory` property

[edit] something like this:

```
state= {
        Category:[
                  {id:'1' , name:'parent_1' , parentId:'0'},
                  {id:'2' , name:'child_1' , parentId:'1'},
                  {id:'3' , name:'child_2' , parentId:'1'},

                  {id:'4' , name:'parent_2' , parentId:'0'},
                  {id:'5' , name:'child_1' , parentId:'4'},
                  {id:'6' , name:'child_2' , parentId:'4'},


                 ],
    }


var parents = state.Category.filter(c => c.parentId === '0').map(o => {
    var parent = Object.assign({}, o);
    parent.subCategory = [];
    return parent;
})


state.Category.filter(c => c.parentId !== '0').forEach(o => {
    var parent = parents.find(p => p.id === o.parentId);
    parent.subCategory.push(Object.assign({}, o));
})

console.log(parents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my solution

```js
    
var parents= this.state.Catgeory.filter(cat => cat.parentId=='0');
for(i in parents){
    let id=parents[i].id;
    parents[i].subCategory= states.Catgeory.filter(cat => cat.parentId==id);
}
this.state.Catgeory=parents;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the using `forEach()`, `find()` and `filter()`. While loop through array you can find the parent add push it to `parent.subCategory`.

```js
let category = 
[
    {id:'1' , name:'parent_1' , parentId:'0'},
    {id:'2' , name:'child_1' , parentId:'1'},
    {id:'3' , name:'child_2' , parentId:'1'},

    {id:'4' , name:'parent_2' , parentId:'0'},
    {id:'5' , name:'child_1' , parentId:'4'},
    {id:'6' , name:'child_2' , parentId:'4'},


]
category.forEach(item =>  {
  if(item.parentId !== '0'){
    let parent = category.find(a => item.parentId === a.id)
    parent.subCategory = parent.subCategory || [];
    parent.subCategory.push(item);
  }
})
category = category.filter(({parentId}) => parentId === '0')
console.log(category)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for collecting all nodes and return the data structure form the root node.

This approach works for depper nested nodes than one level and for unsorted data.

```js
var data = [{ id: '1', name: 'parent_1', parentId: '0' }, { id:'2', name: 'child_1', parentId: '1' }, { id: '3', name: 'child_2', parentId: '1' }, { id: '4', name: 'parent_2', parentId: '0' }, { id: '5', name: 'child_1', parentId: '4' }, { id: '6', name: 'child_2', parentId: '4' }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            o[a.id] = a;
            o[a.parentId] = o[a.parentId] || {};
            o[a.parentId].children = o[a.parentId].children || [];
            o[a.parentId].children.push(a);
        });
        return o[root].children;
    }(data, '0');

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var flatArray =
[
                  {id:'1' , name:'parent_1' , parentId:'0'},
                  {id:'2' , name:'child_1' , parentId:'1'},
                  {id:'3' , name:'child_2' , parentId:'1'},
                  {id:'4' , name:'parent_2' , parentId:'0'},
                  {id:'5' , name:'child_1' , parentId:'4'},
                  {id:'6' , name:'child_2' , parentId:'4'}
                 ];

    for (var a=0; a<flatArray.length; a++) {
        for (var b=0; b<flatArray.length; b++) {
        if(flatArray[a].parentId === flatArray[b].id) {
            if(!!flatArray[b].subCategory){
          flatArray[b].subCategory.push(flatArray[a])
          } else {
          flatArray[b].subCategory = [flatArray[a]]
          }
        }
      }
    }


    var finalArray = flatArray.filter(a => {
        return typeof(a.subCategory) !== 'undefined';
    });
```